# what is fn.split('\\')[1].split('.')[0].strip()?

Tags: transfer-learning

I try to learn transfer_learning and couldn't understand the meaning of coding.
Below is my coding.

```
IMG_DIM = (150, 150)

train_files = glob.glob('training_data/*')

train_imgs = [img_to_array(load_img(img, target_size=IMG_DIM)) for img in train_files]

train_imgs = np.array(train_imgs)

**train_labels = [fn.split('\\')[1].split('.')[0].strip() for fn in train_files]**
```

In the train_files, there are dog images named as (dog.231). So, does a split function used in this code is try to separate dog and number?? Could anyone please explain me the last code?? I also attach the picture for my files name just in case.

[image: file_name]

Answer (score 0):

```
train_labels = [fn.split('/')[1].split('.')[0].strip() for fn in train_files]
```

Checkout this code, it should work.